# Why does replacing the <body> tag in an iframe cause an additional <head> tag to be added?

Tags: javascript, html, dom, iframe

I've run into an interesting problem that I can't find an explanation for. When replacing the `<body>` tag in a iframe (same-origin) with `iframe.document.body.outerHTML = content;` an additional empty `<head>` tag is added to the iframe. This behavior is the same in both Chrome and Firefox (I haven't tested Safari or IE.) The following example show the problem, just inspect the iframe to see the added `<head>` tags.

http://jsfiddle.net/8huj4fxs/

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>iframe problem</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <iframe id="iframe"></iframe>

    <script type="text/javascript">
      var html = '';
      html += '<!doctype html>';
      html += '<html>';
      html += '<head><style type="text/css">h1 { color: red; }</style></head>';
      html += '<body><h1>Title</h1></body>';
      html += '</html>';

      var iframe = document.getElementById('iframe').contentWindow.document;
      iframe.open();
      iframe.write(html);
      iframe.close();

      for(var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        content = '<body><h1>Title '+ i +'</h1></body>';

        document.getElementById('iframe').contentWindow.document.body.outerHTML = content;
      }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Seems like an interesting artefact. Are there any consequences? *document.head* seems to refer to the first one, which is the original.

Comment: I haven't found functional problems any yet. I sure it would mess up some scripts which are only expecting one <head> because its clearly invalid HTML. My OCD is really kill me here.

Comment: I've deleted my answer because I think it was wrong.  I think I missed that the context node should have a head tag already and therefore the fragment parser would skip adding one.  Sorry about that.

Comment: OK I've been looking at this for too long, going through chromium source code, and I'm not AS sure that I was wrong, so I just put the answer back up, for discussion at least.

Answer (score 4):

I'm going to put this back up, at least for further discussion, because I think maybe my initial reasoning might be correct.  I think the *head element pointer* refered to in 16.1 of [3](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/single-page.html#reset-the-insertion-mode-appropriately) might always be null in this case, resulting in a `<head>` element being added.

**Original Answer**

This seemed like an interesting research question... Here's what seems to be happening if i've interpreted the specs properly:

**tl;dr:** When parsing a fragment that has a context of `<html>` (parent of `<body>`), if the fragment doesn't include a `<head>`, an empty one is automatically included.

**Relevant specs:**

1. [outerHTML](https://dvcs.w3.org/hg/innerhtml/raw-file/tip/index.html#attributes)
2. [Parsing HTML fragments](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/single-page.html#html-fragment-parsing-algorithm)
3. [Reset the insertion mode appropriately](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/single-page.html#reset-the-insertion-mode-appropriately)
4. [Before Head insertion mode](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/single-page.html#the-before-head-insertion-mode)

According to the outerHTML spec, when you set this property, you start the browser parsing in a fragment.  Parsing a fragment can be passed a context element. In the case of  outerHTML, the context is set to be the parent of the element that is having its outerHTML set, which in this case is the parent of the `<body>` element of the `<iframe>`, its `<html>` element.

When parsing the input, in your case `'<body><h1>Title '+ i +'</h1></body>'`, the fragment parser starts by creating a new document and `<html>` element attached to it as the root element.  Then, the parser's insertion mode gets [set according to the context](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/single-page.html#reset-the-insertion-mode-appropriately).  The context is an `<html>` element, so insertion mode gets set to *'before head'* according to step 16.1 of [3](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/single-page.html#reset-the-insertion-mode-appropriately).  Then the parser is run with your outerHTML input according to step 6 of [2](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/single-page.html#html-fragment-parsing-algorithm).  The first thing it comes across is the `<body>` tag, which according to [4](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/single-page.html#the-before-head-insertion-mode) means that a `<head>` tag is inserted into the document, and then continues to parse the rest of your input.

When it's done, according to [2](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/single-page.html#html-fragment-parsing-algorithm), all children of the root node are returned, which in addition to your input, includes an empty `<head>` tag, and inserted into the document in place of the `<body>` element that had its `outerHTML` changed.

Hope this helps!

Comment: So this might be said to be a bug in the spec, unless browsers are supposed to remove the extra head on the basis that there should only be one.

Comment: Could be.  It seems like that when parsing a fragment, in the case of the context element being an `<html>` tag, you'd want to check if it has a `<head>` child element instead of checking if the parser has already read in a `<head>` tag.  Not sure...

Comment: Sounds right to me. If I use the original fiddle but change the loop to set the `outerHTML` to `'<head></head><body><h1>Title '+ i +'</h1></body>'`, then I get the same number of heads as with the original fiddle. Why? Because the browser does not need to create new `head` elements.